# How to add parameters to my htaccess in wordpress to make files open in browser instead of download?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file, browser, user-generated-content

I want to add the following...

```
AddType: application/pdf
AddType: application/doc
AddType: application/docx
AddType: application/ppt
AddType: application/ppptx
AddType: application/pps
AddType: application/ppsx
AddType: application/odt
AddType: application/xls
AddType: application/xlsx
AddType: application/rar
AddType: application/zip
```

...to the htaccess code below, so files uploaded by users on my site will open in the browser instead of automatically downloading. I keep getting errors when I add this to the htaccess code in wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the APACHE SERVER instead of the XAMPP ,LAMP OR WAMP etc then you need to follow these steps. 

`Here is the solutions.`

Step -1 : Run this command.
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Step -2: Enable it.
sudo a2enmod php5

Step-3 : Restart apache.
sudo service apache2 restart

After installing, your website will work properly.

Note: if this is not fulfil your requirement then please share the which server you are using then I can also give a suitable solution.
Thanks,